# How to increase the url length limit in WSGI?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wsgi, wsgiserver

I am using WSGI(Web Server Gateway Interface) server for my application.
I am getting 414 error when I exceed 8k characters in the url. However the api calls work fine for url lengths up-to 8k characters.
Does WSGI have any maximum URL limit that is set by default. If yes what is the limit and how to increase/decrease the limit.

Answer (score 0):

As it is written MAX_HEADER_LINE = 8192 present a constant. It also might be configurable. This link might be helpful

https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/blob/579c498ae6b9eb67cace82ac60b85fbc442a58e5/eventlet/wsgi.py#L21